# @OnetoMany entity in @ElementCollection

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many, embeddable

I have 2 entities and 1 embeddable object :

```
@Entity
    class CourseDetails extends Course {
    @Id
    Integer id;
    @ElementCollection
        @CollectionTable(name = "course_section", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "courseId"), foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "course_section_fk"))
        private List<CourseSection> courseSection;
    }
    
    @Embeddable
    public class CourseSection extends BaseBo {
    @OneToMany
        @JoinColumn(name="contentId")
        private Set<CourseContent> courseContent = new HashSet<>();
    }
    
    @Entity
    public class CourseContent {
    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1856738483334146418L;
        @Id
        private Integer contentId;
        private String contentSummary;
    }
```

I want to store coursesection as an embedded object of course and course_section should contain reference of course_content. I tried the above structure but it gives error :

**@ElementCollection cannot be used inside an @Embeddable that is also contained within an @ElementCollection**

How to achieve this in spring boot-jpa ?

Comment: Why do you need it to be an embeddable?

Comment: @DavideD'Alto I need course section to be a part of course and not as a seperate entity

Comment: It just looks like you are trying to shoehorn a Many-To_Many into an element collection.

Comment: @Achyut why? M.Deinum seems to be correct in their assumption with this. Sounds like an https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @M.Deinum Could you please suggest how this relation should be between Course, Course Section and course content. Considering course section to be a composite object of course.

Comment: A composite of what? There doesn't seem to be anything but a collection in there. I also don't see anything that prevents it from being an `@Entity` as well instead of an embeddable.

Comment: @M.Deinum .Thanks, course_section can be an entity, but I think it should be a part of course only and course_section will further store only the reference of all its content